# How to access propertyvalue in FluentModelValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, fluentvalidation

How can I access property value in Fluent Model Validator?. Below is the 
validator class for ModelA. ModelA has a bool property named isValid. 
How can I access the boolean value within this class?.

```
 public class ModelAValidator :  
 AbstractValidator<ModelA>

{

    public ModelAValidator()

    {
       var regexPatterns = new RegExPatterns();
       RuleFor(x => x.FirstName)
          .RequiredForBeneficiaryWhen(x => x.IsBeneficiaryValid)
          .WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_PersonalDetails_1001_firstname)


     RuleFor(x => x.FirstLastName).
            RequiredForBeneficiaryWhen(x => x.IsBeneficiaryValid)
            .WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_PersonalDetails_1001_firstname)

    }

}
```

ExtensionMethod-

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty>   
        RequiredForBeneficiaryWhen<T, TProperty>(
        this IRuleBuilder<T, TProperty> ruleBuilder,     
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> conditionalProperty)
{

        var validationrule = new UnobtrusiveValidationRule()
        {
            ValidationType = "mvfbenefreq"
        };

        return
            ruleBuilder.SetValidator(new  
           BeneficiaryRequiredValidation<T>(conditionalProperty, 
        false, validationrule));
}
```

Property Validator -

```
public class BeneficiaryRequiredValidation<T> : PropertyValidator, IClientValidatable
{
    public object CompareTo { get; private set; }
    public UnobtrusiveValidationRule ClientValidationRule { get; set; }
    private readonly Expression<Func<T, bool>> _conditonalExpression;
    private readonly bool _conditionalValue;


    public BeneficiaryRequiredValidation(Expression<Func<T, bool>> compareExpression, bool conditionalValue , UnobtrusiveValidationRule clientvalidationrule)
        : base(FluentValidation.Resources.Messages.lessthan_error)
    {
        ClientValidationRule = clientvalidationrule;
        _conditonalExpression = compareExpression;
        _conditionalValue = conditionalValue;
    }

    protected override bool IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext context)
    {
        return true;

    }

    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var formatter = new MessageFormatter().AppendPropertyName(metadata.PropertyName);
        var message = formatter.BuildMessage(ErrorMessageSource.GetString());

        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = message,
            ValidationType = ClientValidationRule.ValidationType
        };

        if (ClientValidationRule.Parameterlist != null)
        {
            foreach (var entry in ClientValidationRule.Parameterlist)
            {
                rule.ValidationParameters.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
            }
        }
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to validate IsValid like FirstName or pass it into RequiredForBeneficiaryWhen?

Comment: Yes @bpruitt-goddard

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `RequiredForBeneficiaryWhen` looks something like this:

```
private bool RequiredForBeneficiaryWhen(string requiredStr, bool isValid)
{
    //Require value specified if isValid is true
    if (isValid)
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(requiredStr);

    //It isn't valid
    return false;
}
```

Then you can rewrite the rules like so using `Must`:

```
RuleFor(x => x.FirstName)
        .Must((model, firstName) => RequiredForBeneficiaryWhen(firstName, model.IsBeneficiaryValid))
        .WithLocalizedMessage(ResourceAreas.Messages.Message_PersonalDetails_1001_firstname)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response - What I am trying is to read the model property value and pass it as a parameter to the unobtrusive jquery adapter method.The other model property value is needed for the validation of property which we are validating. Hopefully I  have explained the things clearly. Thankyou @bpruitt-goddard